# Database Joins Done On The Webserver

Tags: database, performance, join, webserver, theory

Today I found [an article online](http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/) discussing Facebooks architecture (though it's a bit dated).  While reading it I noticed under the section **Software that helps Facebook scale**, the third bullet point states:

> Facebook uses MySQL, but primarily as a key-value persistent storage,
>   moving joins and logic onto the web servers since optimizations are
>   easier to perform there (on the “other side” of the Memcached layer).

Why move complex joins to the web server?  Aren't databases optimized to perform join logic?  This methodology seems contrary to what I've learned up to this point, so maybe the explanation is just eluding me.

If possible, could someone explain this (an example would help tremendously) or point me to a good article (or two) for the benefits (and possibly examples) of how and why you'd want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about Facebook, but we have several applications where we follow a similar model. The basis is fairly straightforward.

The database contains huge amounts of data.  Performing joins at the database level really slows down any queries we make on the data, even if we're only returning a small subset. (Say 100 rows of parent data, and 1000 rows of child data in a parent-child relationship for example)

However, using .NET DataSet objects, of we select in the rows we need and then create DataRelation objects within the DataSet, we see a dramatic boost in performance.

I can't answer why this is, as I'm not knowledgeable about the internal workings of either, but I can venture a guess...

The RDBMS (Sql Server in our case) has to deal with the data that lives in files.  These files are very large, and only so much of it can be loaded into memory, even on our heavy-hitter SQL Servers, so it there is a penalty of disk I/O.

When we load a small portion of it into a Dataset, the join is happening entirely in memory, so we lose the I/O penalty of going to the disk.

Even though I can't explain the reason for the performance boost completely (and I'd love to have someone more knowledgeable tell me if my guess is right) I can tell you that in certain cases, when there is a VERY large amount of data, but your app only needs to pull a small subset of it, there is a noticeable boot in performance by following the model described.  We've seen it turn apps that just crawl into lightning-quick apps.

But if done improperly, there is a penalty - if you overload the machine's RAM but doing it inappropriately or in every situation, then you'll have crashes or performance issues as well.